# jQuery UI sortables - get handle on dropped item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I had this working in UI 1.8.6 using [this hack](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/attachment/ticket/4303/sortable-item-sender.patch), but I cant seem to get it to work in 1.8.17.

- I want to drag items from a list into a sortable.
- The items should remain in the source list after dropping (so they can be added n times)
- when i drop the item into the sortable, i want to get a handle on the instance of the dropped item in the sortable.

In the receive method of the sortable:

```
receive: function(e, ui){
    // ui.item is the original dragged item, not the clone that gets created when dropped
    // ui.helper is a separate clone of the dragged item, it does not get inserted into the sortable
}
```

so the question is, how do I get a handle on the inserted item? It seems the item hasn't been inserted (or created) by the time receive is called. Has a change been made to jquery UI or am I missing something?

here's my code:

```
$('form').sortable({
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    receive: function (ev, ui) {
        // need handle on dropped item here. ui.item and ui.helper are not it
    }
});


$('.draggableTings').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
    , appendTo: "body"
    , revert: "invalid"
    , connectToSortable: "form"
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing this

```
_uiHash: function(inst) {
    var self = inst || this;
    return {
        helper: self.helper,
        placeholder: self.placeholder || $([]),
        position: self.position,
        originalPosition: self.originalPosition,
        offset: self.positionAbs,
        item: self.currentItem,
        sender: inst ? inst.element : null
    };
}
```

with this

```
_uiHash: function(inst) {
    var self = inst || this;
    return {
        helper: self.helper,
        placeholder: self.placeholder || $([]),
        position: self.position,
        originalPosition: self.originalPosition,
        offset: self.positionAbs,
        item: this.fromOutside ? this.currentItem : self.currentItem,
        sender: inst ? inst.element : null
    };
}
```

seems to have done the trick, nasty though. and probably not fool proof